# kivy. Обновление gridlayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Есть gridlayout  и я его при определенных условиях обновляю методом `clear_widgets()`, только вот, как я понял, внутренние виджеты не удаляются из памяти, а просто извлекаются из цикла, потому как потребляемая память растет.

Есть идея создать список из виджетов, а потом в цикле обходить каждый виджет по индексу и менять его внутренние параметры (текст, цвет фона и т.д.), но... Но может это глупость и есть какой способ проще?

Comment: Идея удалять и заново создавать объекты, конечно, не очень хорошая, если можно просто изменить свойство уже созданного объекта по его id.

Comment: Изменять по id было бы не плохо) А можно ли присвоить id в коде?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Но все равно придется проходить весь GridLayout.children в поисках нужного объекта по id.

Comment: В документации начал искать что-то по поводу children и... Тут вы кидание образец) И мне к примеру, не совсем обязательно присваивать id, потому как, я все кнопки буду обновлять. Пройдусь по циклу for child in root.children. Это если я правильно понял пример из документации.

Comment: Я не знаю, чего вы хотите. Код ваш не видел.

Comment: Ну, а так, да,можно for child in children.

Comment: Так и получилось)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=3
        self.padding=10
        self.nums=[7,8,9,
                   4,5,6,
                   1,2,3]
        for i in self.nums:
            self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i),on_press=self.update_button_text))

    def draw(self):
        return self

#обновление текста кнопки
    def update_button_text(self,instance):
        random.shuffle(self.nums)
        for i in self.children:#проходим каждый дочерний виджет в этом цикле
            i.text=str(random.choice(self.nums))#меняем значение в виджете


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        a=MyGrid()
        b=a.draw()
        return b


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Это ответ по вашему вопросу или уточнение кода?

Comment: Да ответ. Но тот другой вариант кода мне все равно пригодится в будущем, когда нужно будет изменять конкретный дочерний виджет.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string("""<MyGui@BoxLayout>:""")
        root = Factory.MyGui()
        root.add_widget(Button(id='button', on_press=self.get_id))
        return root

    def get_id(self, instance):
        print(instance.id)


Test().run()
```